# Error when adding a button to a view yosemite. "NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview: "

Tags: objective-c, xcode, osx-yosemite

**The part of my code is:**

```
 NSWindow *appWindow = [NSApp appWindow];

    NSView *superview = [[appWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton] superview];

    NSRect frame;

    frame.size = NSMakeSize([self.mBuyFullVersionView frame].size.width,[self.mBuyFullVersionView frame].size.height);

    frame.origin.y =[superview frame].size.height - [self.mBuyFullVersionView frame].size.height -kVerticalSpacing;

    frame.origin.x =[superview frame].size.width - [self.mBuyFullVersionView frame].size.width - kHorizontalSpacing - 6;

    [self.mBuyFullVersionView setFrame:frame];

    [superview addSubview: self.mBuyFullVersionView];
```

Comment: Have you instantiated mBuyFullVersionView anyplace? Is mBuyFullVersionView NULL when you execute this code?

Comment: mBuyFullVersionView is an outlet. And after searching in google I came to know that we have to use NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController. But I don't know how to use. Can you please provide me a code snippet so that I can understand it clearly?Please.

Comment: Try looking at this: https://github.com/rodionovd/Locatr/blob/master/Locatr/LRMainWindowController.m

Comment: Also https://github.com/rodionovd/Locatr/blob/master/Locatr/LRTitlebarAccessoryViewController.h and https://github.com/rodionovd/Locatr/blob/master/Locatr/LRTitlebarAccessoryViewController.m

Answer (score 7):

“NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview:…" is, as it says, an warning by NSWindow. The warning appears when subviews are added directly onto the windows *backgroundView*, called borderView, not its contentView.
This warning is harmless, but it is not recommended to add views to the backgroundView, as this may break in the future.

If you want to add views to the titleBar, you can use either a toolbar or the NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController. For everything else use the contentView of the window.

From Apples API Release Notes:

> NSWindow has never supported clients adding subviews to anything other than the contentView. Some applications would add subviews to the contentView.superview (also known as the border view of the window). NSWindow will now log when it detects this scenario: "NSWindow warning: adding an unknown subview:". Applications doing this will need to fix this problem, as it prevents new features on 10.10 from working properly. See titlebarAccessoryViewControllers for official API.
>
> NSWindow now has the ability to add officially known subviews to the titlebar/toolbar area. The views are to be wrapped with a new NSViewController subclass called NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController and added to the window with the "titlebarAccessoryViewControllers" API. There are a set of methods to add and insert the titlebarAccessoryViewControllers, such as addTitlebarAccessoryViewController: and removeTitlebarAccessoryViewControllerAtIndex:. However, one can also utilize "removeFromParentViewController" to easily remove a given child view controller. NSTitlebarAccessoryViewController has a property to tell NSWindow where to place the view (layoutAttribute) and a property to determine how it behaves in full screen (fullScreenMinHeight). The NSToolbar fullScreenAccessoryView API is now deprecated, and clients should utilize this new API.